# Finding center and zoom level in leaflet, given a list of lat-long pairs

Tags: javascript, gis, openstreetmap, leaflet

I have a list of lat long pairs. (Or I could create GeoJSON). I want to map them all on leaflet map.

How do I find what should I set as the center and as the zoom level so that all the points show up.

All the leaflet examples seem to use a fixed center and zoom, but I am accepting user input so I need to calculate them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is with a `LatLngBounds` object. You can then have the map [fitBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds). Or get its center [manually](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-getcenter) if you prefer.

```
var myPoints = [[1,1],[2,2] /*, ...*/ ];
var myBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(myPoints);
myMap.fitBounds(myBounds); //Centers and zooms the map around the bounds
```

You can even forgo instantiating the bounds object if you would like:

```
myMap.fitBounds([[1,1],[2,2] /*, ...*/ ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to use GeoJSON and create your leaflet map as described in the [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html). Than you can simply use `geojsonLayer.getBounds()` together with `map.setBounds()` to zoom to your data.